# Dont hide SplitViewController in portrait mode

Tags: iphone, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I am developing an app for iPad & for iOS >= 4 , and I am using split view controller.

But I don't want to hide master panel in portrait mode.

For iOS 5, I can use

```
-(BOOL)splitViewController:shouldHideViewController:inOrientation;
```

but for < 5 what to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Matt Gemmell's [MGSplitViewController](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad/)

Comment: I guess you'll have to start all over for this, which you might not want!

Comment: Yes, he has to start from 0 as default controller doesn't provide functionality what he wants. And feasibility study should be done before start programming.